# Deployment HTML CSS project on Netlify & Vercel with error 404 showing

Tags: html, css, deployment, netlify, vercel

I have been trying to run the below project for CSS Layout on both Netlify & Vercel with error 404 showing,
[https://github.com/MMHAtta/CSS-Layout.git](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
bulid log for vercel shows "Build Cache not found"
projuct runs with no issues on local host VSC on the Go Live option.

Comment: Please check [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your git repo has the following files:

```
CSS Layout Checkpoint.css
CSS Layout Checkpoint.html
New Text Document.txt
```

Since you haven't provided much info, I can only guess. Not sure about Vercel, but Netlify requires your home page to be named `index.html` to work fine. So, if you rename `CSS Layout Checkpoint.html` to `index.html`, the 404 error should go away. Vercel *should* then give similar results.